# AngularFirestoreCollection snapshotChanges() does not emit value in service constructor

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a user service which i'm going to add to manage roles in my firebase cloud firestore beta service database. I already added the collection and some documents to the database. The service is injected into another method so i was thinking the constructor in the service would fire and load the collection, however snapshotChanges() never emits a values as the data is never logged to the console, and so the collection never loads.

Was wondering if there is an issue having this code run in the the service constructor?

**app.module.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import {UserService} from './user.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private auth: AuthService, router: Router, private userService: UserService) {
    auth.user$.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
          const returnUrl = localStorage.getItem('returnUrl');
          router.navigateByUrl(returnUrl);
          userService.getAppUsers();
          userService.addUser(user);
      }
    });
  }

}
```

**user.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

interface AppUser {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  isAdmin: boolean;
}

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  AppUserCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<AppUser>;
  AppUsers$: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(public db: AngularFirestore) {
    this.AppUserCollection = this.db.collection('users');
  }

  getAppUsers() {
    alert("here");
    return this.AppUsers$ = this.AppUserCollection.snapshotChanges()
    .map(actions => {
      alert('there');
      return actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as AppUser;
        console.log('Data' + data);
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, data };
      });
    });
  }
    addUser(user: firebase.User) {
      this.db.collection('users').add({'name': user.displayName, 'email': user.email, 'isAdmin': false});
  }
    // }
}
```

Comment: Try adding services before  router.navigateByUrl(returnUrl)

Comment: test it yourself. there's not much code. no point in giving solutions you're guessing on

Answer (score 0):

Try subscribing to this.AppUsers.

```
this.AppUsers = this.AppUserCollection.snapshotChanges()
    .map(actions => {
    return actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as AppUser;
        console.log('Data' + data);
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, data };
    }).subscribe();
```

Comment: Updated my answer.